I am using the swiper library and a flickering phenomenon occurs
<Swiper
    className='main_swiper'
    modules={[Pagination, Autoplay]}
    pagination={{ clickable: true }}
    navigation={{
        nextEl: '.swipers-next',
        prevEl: '.swipers-prev',
    }}
    speed={1500}
    // loop={true}
    autoplay={{ delay: 5000, disableOnInteraction: false }}
    slidesPerView={3}
    onSwiper={(swiper) => setItemSwiper(swiper)}
>
    {imgList.map((el, idx) => (
        <SwiperSlide key={idx}>
            <S.Main_Carousel_Img src={`/${el.name}.jpeg`} alt='main_carousel' />
            <S.Main_Title>{el.title}</S.Main_Title>
        </SwiperSlide>
    ))}
</Swiper>

I'm using swiper, but every time I refresh the page, it flickers for a very brief moment.
What I discovered after many tests is that when the value of slidesPerView is set to 1, this flickering does not occur, but when there are two or more sliding elements, flickering occurs.
Can I get a solution for this ?
I gave a class to the swiperSlide tag and applied CSS as a global style in app.js, but the problem was not solved.
